# Updating a presenting view controller's property inside the modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I was wondering how I would be able to update a view controller `property` of the presenting view controller from a method called inside the modal view controller? Right now, the only way I could think of is using `NSNotificationCenter`, and while this works for Dictionary items, I couldn't figure out how to use it for a custom object.

For example, my presenting view controller `HomewViewController` has a Parse `PFObject` called `homeSelections`, which the could be updated in the modally presented `ModalViewController`'s property `newSelections` (and also a `PFObject`) . After the user makes her selections, I would like `HomeViewController`'s `homeSelections` to also have the latest data passed from the modal view controller.

Help is appreciated - thanks.

**Update 1**: here is what I have done now (note that I am using a stripped down example to test things out)

In `ViewController` (this is the parent/presenting view controller)

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *totalRamen;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.totalRamen = @[@"ramen1", @"ramen2", @"ramen3", @"moot"];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"self.totalRamen: %@", self.totalRamen);
    NSLog(@"Done");
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showModal"]){
        ModalViewController *destinationVC = (ModalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.passedRamen = self.totalRamen;
    }
}

- (IBAction)showModalAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    ModalViewController *destinaionViewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    destinaionViewController.selectionCallback = ^(id selectedItem) {
        self.totalRamen = (NSArray *)selectedItem;
        NSLog(@"self.totalRAmen %@", self.totalRamen);
        NSLog(@"done");
    };
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showModal" sender:self];
}
```

In `ModalViewController` (this is the presented/modal view controller)

```
@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *passedRamen;
- (IBAction)dismissModal:(UIButton *)sender;

typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id value);
@property (nonatomic, copy) CallbackBlock selectionCallback;

@end

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"Passed ramen %@", self.passedRamen);
    NSLog(@"Done");

    self.passedRamen = @[@"moot is awesome"];
    NSLog(@"new ramen: %@", self.passedRamen);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectionCallback); //nil here

    //call back
    CallbackBlock selectionCallback = self.selectionCallback;
    if (selectionCallback){
        selectionCallback(self.passedRamen); //I want to send the newly updated self.passedRamen back
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No show"); //Means if isn't called
    }
}

- (IBAction)dismissModal:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Pass a callback block into the presented view controller or use delegation. Blocks are the cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @CrimsonChris - is there a code sample that I could check out about how to do this? I feel like this is an important concept and I want to make sure to get it right when I implement this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for point it out. I am a bit confused: I thought I was following the suggestion of `PresentedViewController *vc = [[PresentedViewController alloc] init];`. and using the `vc.selectionCallback` in the next line? Based on the code snippet, should I be calling the callback another way?

Comment: You are setting the callback correctly, just on the wrong instance of your modal view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a callback block into the presented view controller. This way the presented view controller doesn't know anything about the view controller presenting it. Much more flexible because now *anybody* can present your view controller, they just pass it a block!

## PresentingViewController

```
PresentedViewController *vc = [[PresentedViewController alloc] init]; //or get your existing one
vc.selectionCallback = ^(id selectedItem) {
    //update selected items here
};
//present vc here
```

## PresentedViewController

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id value);

@property (nonatomic, copy) CallbackBlock selectionCallback;

- (void)somethingWasSelected:(id)selectedItem {
    CallbackBlock selectionCallback = self.selectionCallback;
    if (selectionCallback) selectionCallback(selectedItem);
}
```

*Beware of retain cycles*. This block is being retained by the presented view controller so references to the presented view controller in the block without weakifying it first will create a leak. More info on this can be found [here](http://blog.aceontech.com/post/111694918560/weakify-self-a-more-elegant-solution-to).

Comment: Quick question: I tested the suggested code, but am having an issue where `self.selectionCallback` isn't being populated so whats inside the `if` statement never gets fired. I was wondering what self.selectionCallBack is populated with? Thanks!

Comment: @daspianist This line is setting the callback block. `vc.selectionCallback = ^(id selectedItem) { //update selected items here };`

Comment: So here is what I did inside the `{}` self.totalRamen = (NSArray *)selectedItem;
NSLog(@"self.totalRamen %@", self.totalRamen); NSLog(@"done"); I've also set a break point inside, but it was never called.

Comment: This line is the problem `ModalViewController *destinaionViewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];`. You are creating a brand new ModalViewController and then never using it. Move the callback code into prepareForSegue where you have the ModalViewController that is actually being presented.

Comment: Great just saw this now - will try!

Comment: Thanks for your patience - this worked great and I learned something new and super useful.

Comment: I wish I used this in all my old projet, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> After the user makes her selections, I would like HomeViewController's
>   homeSelections to also have the latest data passed from the modal view
>   controller.

The easy way is to avoid having `ModalViewController` update `HomeViewController` at all. Turn the communication around -- have `HomeViewController` query `ModalViewController` and update itself when the modal is dismissed.

`HomeViewController` already depends on `ModalViewController` -- it has to know about `ModalViewController` in order to present it. So there's no harm in having it also know how to read the `newSelections` property out of `ModalViewController` at the appropriate time. `ModalViewController`, on the other hand, has no need to know anything about where its information goes. It doesn't need to know about `HomeViewController` in order to do its job. If you avoid telling `ModalViewController` anything about `HomeViewController`, you can easily use `ModalViewController` from some other view controller should the need for that ever arise. More importantly, you avoid ever needing to update `ModalViewController` if `HomeViewController` changes.

For example, your `HomeViewController` might look (in part) like this:

```
- (void)showModalViewController
{
    self.modalViewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init]; // or otherwise get the modal controller
    [self presentViewController:self.modalViewController
                       animated:YES 
                     completion:];
}

- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    self.homeSelections = self.modalViewController.newSelections;
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    self.modalViewController = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Caleb. When you say have `HomeViewController` query `ModalViewController`, would you explain a bit more about what you mean by "query" in terms of like an example method? Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially the delegate approach. ModalViewController tells its delegate(HomeViewController) to dismiss it. Then HomeViewController dismisses it but _first_ asks the ModalViewController what its selected items were.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Not really -- the delegate approach would involve passing a pointer to a `delegate` object into `ModalViewController` and having `ModalViewController` call some delegate method at certain times. Instead, I'm advocating letting the presenting controller pull the data it needs out of the controller it presents. It's more passive, doesn't require any knowledge of anything on the part of `ModalViewController` or any delegate protocol to implement in `HomeViewController`.

Comment: @Caleb How would the presenting view controller know _when_ to ask the presented view controller for its selected items?

Comment: The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the presented view controller. In most cases, a presenting view controller doesn't really need to be updated until the presented view controller is dismissed.

Comment: @daspianist By "query" I just mean that the presenting view controller gets the value of the property. I'll add an example above.

Comment: @Caleb If the parent is responsible for dismissing (which I agree with), then how does the parent know _when_ to dismiss? The answer is usually delegation. The approach you are advocating for is your answer is the delegate pattern.

Comment: @Caleb The code snippet you've provided doesn't work as you expect it to. The completion block runs after the presentation animation finishes, _not_ when the modal view is dismissed.

Comment: @CrimsonChris You're quite right on the second point -- don't know what I was thinking. ;-) About *when* to dismiss... I usually have modal view controllers dismiss themselves. From the docs for `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`: *If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.* I suppose you could call it a form of delegation, but it's really not what most people think of when they think of that pattern -- the presented controller isn't delegating, it's just doing it's thing.

Comment: @Caleb I find it bad practice to have view controllers dismiss themselves. It prevents that view controller from being used it places where it is _not_ being presented.

Comment: You're right -- it does prevent that. I'm not sure I'd go so far as to call it a "bad practice," but either way, I think we at least agree that it's good to avoid having `ModalViewController` depend on the class that presents it.